# Merge two large datasets by ID and timestamp, and also get measurements for next n time intervals in R

Tags: r, merge, timestamp, large-data

I want to merge two files using a unique ID and timestamp, and also get measurements for next next n intervals.

The first file has over 15,000 unique IDs. Each ID has measurements taken at 15 minute intervals from Jan 1, 00:00 to Dec 31, 23:45. The database is quite big (35 GB) with over 500 million rows. The file looks something like this.

**First file**
| ID |      Time     | Measurement|
|:----:|:---------------:|:------:|
|  1 |2012-12-31 22:45|  61  |
|  1 |2012-12-31 23:00|  60  |
|  1 |2012-12-31 23:15|  61  |
|  1 |2012-12-31 23:30|  59  |
|  1 |2012-12-31 23:45|  59  |
|  2 |2012-01-01 0:00|  60  |
|  2 |2012-01-01 0:15|  61  |
|  2 |2012-01-01 0:30|  60  |
|  2 |2012-01-01 0:45|  62  |

The second file has unique IDs and a timestamp. IDs in this file is a subset of IDs in the first file. The file is realtively small (~50 MB) compared to the first file.

**Second file**
| ID |      Time     |
|:----:|:---------------:|
|  1 |2012-12-31 22:48|
|  1 |2012-12-31 23:48|
|  2 |2012-01-01 0:16|

I want to merge the two files such that the measurements are extracted for current interval, and the next n intervals. I also want to be able to specify n and and run the code dynamically.

The merged file file should look like this for n = 3. For example, for the second row the measurements for next intervals should not be derived from another ID.

**After merge**
| ID |      Time     | Measurement 1| Measurement 2| Measurement 3|
|:----:|:---------------:|:----:|:---------------:|:----:|
| 1 |      2012-12-31 22:48| 61| 60| 61 |
| 1 |      2012-12-31 23:48| 59| 59| 59 |
| 2 |      2012-01-01 0:16| 61| 60| 62 |

Comment: Hi. Welcome to stackoverflow. Please add minimal samples to your question for other users to work on your problems. Use `dput(head(df))` for example which will allow users to copy your data and work with it. Please do so for inputs and expected output.s.

Comment: Hi @DiT!  This could easily be done in R for a smaller dataset — I've already hammered out that solution — but I suspect a dataset of this size could strain memory and performance limits.  Do you pull this data from (say) an SQL database of some kind?  If so, some of the requisite `JOIN`s could possibly be performed via SQL (with `n` as a dynamic parameter determined in R), and the (much smaller) result set from that query could then be pulled into R, where the remaining transformations are quite manageable.